# How to click next span element in Selenium web driver

Tags: java, selenium

I want to click a href link, then go back to previous page, then click next href link which has text "Meer info".

I wrote following code, but it is producing an Exception. I can go to web then click first link that I want to click with text name "Meer info" than go to back but then I want to click second `linkText` also with the same text name "Meer info" but I don't know how to do that.

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://turksegids.nl/index.php");
Thread.sleep(3000);
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type='image'][value='Zoek!']")).click();
Thread.sleep(5000);
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Meer info")).click();
Thread.sleep(4000);
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Terug naar de resultatenpagina")).click();
Thread.sleep(8000);
driver.findElement(By.linkText("//a[text()=\"Meer info\"]/following- 
sibling::a[2]")).click();

Thread.sleep(4000);
driver.close();
driver.quit();
```

I am getting this Exception

```
Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"//a[text()=\"Meer info\"]/following-sibling::a[2]"}
```

Comment: Hi Muratcan, your entire script seems to be wrong; let me send you the right one shortly

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://turksegids.nl/index.php");
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type='image'][value='Zoek!']")).click();
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Meer info")).click();
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Terug naar de resultatenpagina")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='resultatenklik_28957_info']/u")).click();
driver.close();
driver.quit();
```

and see it works or not

Answer (score 1):

Try to use

```
List<WebElement> element = driver.findElements(By.linkText("Meer info"));
element.get(2).click();
```

instead of

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("//a[text()=\"Meer info\"]/following- 
sibling::a[2]")).click();
```

It will work !!

Comment: let me know if you still face issues; I have alternate answers for you .  Sams | seleniumworks.com